# : undefined reference to `testClass::sum()'

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class testClass
{
public:
    int sum();
    //Postcondition: Returns the sum of the 
    //               private data members.
    void print();
    //Prints the values of the private data members.
    testClass();
    //default constructor
    //Postcondition: x = 0; y = 0;
    testClass(int a, int b);
    //Constructor with parameters
    //Initializes the private data members to the
    //values specified by the parameters.
    //Postconditon: x = a; y = b
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

int sum() 
{
    int a, b, total;
    total = a + b;
    return total;
}

void print()
{
    cout<< "sum = " << sum() << endl;
}
testClass::testClass()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

testClass::testClass(int a, int b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

This program compiles 100% okay but when I run it I get the following errors:
--------------------Configuration: mingw5 - CUI Debug, Builder Type: MinGW--------------------

Checking file dependency...
Linking...
[Error] C:\Dev-Cpp\MAlikChapter1\Exercise14.cpp:56: undefined reference to `testClass::sum()'
[Error] C:\Dev-Cpp\MAlikChapter1\Exercise14.cpp:58: undefined reference to`testClass::print()'
[Error] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Complete Make Exercise14: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)

```
int main()
{
    int m, n;
    testClass mySum;
    testClass myPrint;
    mySum.sum();

    myPrint.print();
}
```

This is an example program from: Malik "Data structures using C++"

Comment: Where have you implemented `testClass::sum` and `testClass::print`?

Comment: You declare the `sum` and `print` functions, but never define them

Comment: you forgot adding `testClass::` before `sum` and `print`. If you define it outside the class you will need to add it

Answer (score 4):

Add `testClass::` before the name of functions `sum` and `print` when implementing them outside the class:

```
int testClass::sum() 
{
    // ...
}
void testClass::print()
{
    // ...
}
```

This will solve the undefined reference error, but you have another error in your `sum` function. You're declaring local `a` and `b` variables without initializing them, and then using them in an expression `a + b`. Either initialize them with something, or if you want to sum the class members `x` and `y`, then use those variables instead of `a` and `b`, they will be accessible after adding `testClass::`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked 100% okay after adding testClass::sum() and testClass::print() and initializing them.

Comment: This question can now be closed